# Is there a JSONParser method to parse the following string structure in Java?

Tags: java, json

My JSON String output is as below.
`{'errorcode': '0', 'errormessage': "'success'", 'parsedoutput': [{'columnname': 'salary', 'columnalias': 'sal', 'tablename': 'employee', 'expression': 'salary', 'schemaname': 'prod', 'tablealias': 'e'}]}`

And I want to parse this string and get the values. Gone thru many links here but found none working to my requirement. So posted as new question, hope no issues.

Error I'm getting when I run my code:

```
Unexpected character (') at position 1.
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsontostring.JSONToStringTest.main(JSONToStringTest.java:18)
```

My Java Code which I used to parse the json string..

```
public class JSONToStringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String jsonString = "{'errorcode': '0', 'errormessage': \"'success'\", 'parsedoutput': [{'columnname': 'salary', 'columnalias': 'sal', 'tablename': 'employee', 'expression': 'salary', 'schemaname': 'prod', 'tablealias': 'e'}]}";

    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject)parser.parse(jsonString);

        System.out.println(json.get("errorcode"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is success in both double and single quotes?

Comment: `jsonString = jsonString.replace("\'\"", "\"").replace("\"\'", "\"").replace('\'', '\"');` and than parse.

Comment: @AliBeyit ideally double quotes are not supposed to show in output but I'm getting it that way and I'm checking it with the person who shared it to me.

Comment: You'll need something different than a json parser, since your input isnt json

Comment: agree with @codeflush.dev

Comment: @JoopEggen your suggestion worked like charm, thanks mate

Comment: Now I'm getting a different output like this.. `{'errormessage': "'Unexpected", 'errorcode': '1'}` and it's giving me error `TypeError: can't convert {'errormessage': "'Unexpected", 'errorcode': '1'} to java.lang.String`. Help me on this one

Answer (score 0):

As others commented under original post, your JSON string is not valid. Therefore, one way is to parse the given string directly and the other way is to make the invalid JSON string be valid, then parse it by any popular JSON libraries.

**Method 1**
If you are using JAVA 8, you can easily retrieve the value of `errorcode` with `Stream` as follows:

```
String errorCode = Arrays.asList(jsonStr.split(","))
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.contains("errorcode"))
    .findFirst()
    .get()
    .split(":")[1]
    .trim()
    .replace("'", "");
    System.out.println(errorCode);
```

**Method 2**

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr.replace("'", "\"").replace("\"\"", "\""));
String errorCode = jsonObj.get("errorcode").toString();
System.out.println(errorCode);
```

Comment: A third way is to FIX whatever (or whoever) is generating the invalid JSON.

Comment: @Stephen C Ha, I totally agree with you!

Comment: I'm getting output like this..  

`{'errormessage': "'Unexpected", 'errorcode': '1'}` and it's giving me error  

`TypeError: can't convert {'errormessage': "'Unexpected", 'errorcode': '1'} to java.lang.String`. Help me on this one.

Comment: @LHCHIN I haven't gone to that level. I'm calling a py script and it inturn gives me the output `{'errormessage': "'Unexpected", 'errorcode': '1'}` but in java I'm not able to take it as String or JSONObject. Not sure how to make changes here

Comment: @mannedear Hi, I think you should create another post for this exception.